# Truncating svg text to fit a rect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, truncate

What i need is to truncate a text so that it fills the size of a `svg` rectangle and then popup to its full-size on `mouse-over`.
I have tried with css using the following code to hide the text and then popup but it doesnt seem to work.

```
#text_trunc {
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#text_trunc:hover{
    overflow: visible; 
    white-space: normal; 
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

I have created all the `svg` elements using `javascript` and this is where i create an `id` for the text element

`text.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "text_trunc");`

My best guess is that `svg` creates an image which cannot be truncated by `css`...still need a solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "overflow" CSS property won't work in SVGs because `<text>` elements have no "box" to overflow.

You could try experimenting with the "clip-path" property instead.  It is a CSS property specific to SVGs.  You would need to define a clip path in your SVG that was the size of the truncated box.  Then add and remove it with your CSS rules.

```
#text_trunc {
    clip-path: url(#truncbox);
}

#text_trunc:hover{
    clip-path: none;
}
```

Unfortunately, this solution doesn't allow for fancier behaviour like automatic ellipses.

Answer (score -1):

i  think the following url  will help you

http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/12984/css-display-hidden-text-on-rollover/p1